# PDF url is behaving differently in Selenium and normal application

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

i am facing a weird issue in Selenium. i have a option in my application, and when i click on that option it will open a pdf file in new window. but when i am running the same in Selenium Java Automation it is downloading the file from that option. (it is opening new tab quickly and file started downloading and new tab also closed once file started downloading)

does any body have a solution for this.

Comment: Could you please provide the URL?

Comment: Sorry actually it's a client application, so i can't be able to share it

Comment: You can try with any other public URL''s which has these feature of PDF downloading. If you facing issue in this public URL you can share it

Comment: The ways PDFs are managed is machine specific and can be configured. Can i please suggest you think one step up from what you're asking. Why do you want it open? What are you going to do with the pdf? - Selenium won't be able to do anything with it...  If anything, downloading the file would be more beneficial so you can access it outside the browser.  If you can share more information someone might be able to help and this won't be a problem :-)

Comment: Cause of the different behavior is in different browser profiles. Selenium uses (by default) new temporary profile. If you run selenium test using existing browser profile you can achieve desired behavior by setting up opening PDF instead of downloading etc. including browser extensions.